# sqlite file is shown empty in python and r

Tags: python, r, sqlite, rsqlite

I am trying to open a .sqlite3 file in python but I see no information is returned. So I tried r and still get empty for tables. I would like to know what tables are in this file.
I used the following code for python:

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to the SQLite database
        specified by the db_file
    :param db_file: database file
    :return: Connection object or None
    """
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

    return None
database = "D:\\...\assignee.sqlite3"
conn = create_connection(database)
cur = conn.cursor()
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

but rows are empty!
This is where I got the assignee.sqlite3 from:
https://github.com/funginstitute/downloads

I also tried RStudio, below is the code and results:

```
> con <- dbConnect(drv=RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname="D:/.../assignee")
> tables <- dbListTables(con)
```

But this is what I get
[image]

Comment: You're not actually running a query on the database... try `SELECT count(*) FROM assignee`

Comment: @Shawn I am pretty new to this concept. I do not know what tables are in there to run a query. I get this error when I try your command: File "<ipython-input-29-034b731f512d>", line 1
    SELECT count(*) FROM assignee
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `assignee` is the only one in that database. (It's not a very good schema design).

Comment: So I can get the number of rows, but how actually I am able to see the content? I mean the columns and values?

Comment: @MaryamRahmaniMoghaddam download the tools belows and navigate to your db and selected it should retrive the tables , also , try changing your connection path to the one provided on my answer , let me know if this works for u

Comment: You can view the table definition including column names in the sqlite3 shell with the `.schema` command, or whatever other admin tool you want. And you get the content by selecting from the table in a sql query that your python (Or whatever) program executes...

Answer (score 0):

first make sure you provided correct path on your  connection string to the sql
 light db  ,
use this conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\users\guest\desktop\example.db")

also make sure you are using the SQLite library in the unit tests and the production code

check the types of sqllite connection strings and determain which one your db belongs to :

Basic
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;
Version 2 is not supported by this class library.

SQLite

In-Memory Database

An SQLite database is normally stored on disk but the database can also be

stored in memory. Read more about SQLite in-memory databases.

Data Source=:memory:;Version=3;New=True;

SQLite

Using UTF16
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;UseUTF16Encoding=True;

SQLite
With password
Data Source=c:\mydb.db;Version=3;Password=myPassword;

so make sure you wrote the proper connection string for your sql lite  db

if you still cannot see it, check if  the disk containing /tmp full otherwise ,  it might be encrypted database, or locked and used by some other application maybe  , you may confirm that by using one of the many tools for sql light database ,

you may downliad this tool , try to navigate directly to where your db exist and it will give you indication of the problem .

[download windows version](https://download.sqlitebrowser.org/DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.10.1-win32.exe)

[Download Mac Version](https://download.sqlitebrowser.org/DB.Browser.for.SQLite-3.10.1.dmg)

[Download linux version](https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/archive/v3.10.1.tar.gz)

good luck